# Overloaded ostream operator error in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I try to overload ostream operator in a class Student as follows:

```
//Student.h
class Student
{
    public:
        Student(){}
        ~Student(){}
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&,const Student&);
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&,const Student&);
    private:
        char* snum;
};

//Student.cpp
#include "Student.h"
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output,const Student& c)
{
    output<<c.snum<<", "<<c.name<<", "<<c.email<<endl;
    return output;
}
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input,const Student& cN)
{
    cout<<"Input number: ";
    input>>cN.snum;
    return input;
}

//main.cpp
#include "Student.h"
int main() 
{
    Student st;
    std::cin >> st;
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But when i input the snum,i get error message "Segmentation Fault".
I change `char* snum;` to `char snum;`,it return compiler error `The operation "std::istream>> const char" is illegal.`
Thank you for help.

Comment: `snum` doesn't point to anything. Use a `std::string`.

Comment: @user657267 the error message is `The operation "std::istream>> const std::string " is illegal.`

Comment: `std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Student& cN)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need that *snum* will point on allocate memory and then you can input it with data, for exemple:

```
   char* p_var = new char[20]; // 20 bytes allocation 

   // ... using p_var

   delete[] p_var; // Releasep_var memory
```

In your case, you should do the allocation in the Ctor and the release in the Dtor.
you can read this for more info:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Answer (score 1):

tell me if your problem got solved by using below changes...

```
class Student
{
     private:
        char snum;
        char name;
        char email;
    public:
        Student(){};
        ~Student(){};
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&,Student&);
        friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream&,Student&);

};


std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& output,Student& c)
{
    output<<c.snum<<", "<<c.name<<", "<<c.email<<endl;
    return output;
}
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& input, Student& cN)
{
    cout<<"Input number: ";
    input>>cN.snum;
    input>>cN.name;
    input>>cN.email;
    return input;
}


int main() 
{
    Student st;
   std::cin >> st;
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

use string or char array or assign char *x some memory before using for cin...

Comment: Thank you.Just allocate memory in constructor before using a pointer and the problem got solved.